# ¿Cómo escribir varios nombres con el mismo apellido?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, nombres-propios

¿Cómo podría escribir estos nombres sin perder los nombres individuales?

> Melina Alvárez, Celina Alvárez, Betty Alvárez, Luis Alvárez y Héctor
>   Barquero

Se podría escribir:

> Melina, Celina, Betty y Luis Alvárez y Héctor Barquero

Aunque se escucharía mejor:

> Héctor Barquero, Melina, Celina, Betty y Luis Alvárez

Me gusta más la última forma, ¿pero es válida?
¿Debiera de llevar un punto y coma luego de Hector Barquero?

Actualización:
He tomado de mientras la solución de @Gustavson a menos que me la cambien en el departamento de lingüística.

> Héctor Barquero y los hermanos Alvárez – Luis, Melina, Celina y Betty – por estar presentes ...

Le agradezco también a @Karlomanio y @pablodf76 por aportar.

Actualización: No es legal, sólo formal.

Comment: No sé si es váldo o no, pero se podría decir también- Héctor Barquero y Los Alvarez- Melina, Celina, Betty y Luis

Comment: No estoy seguro de que haya una regla para esto (por eso no lo hago una respuesta), pero yo usaría una [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) después de "Álvarez" en tu primera opción.

Comment: En un texto legal, debería repetirse el apellido por cada persona que lo posea. Si el texto no es legal, me inclino por la opción de Karlomanio, o por decir: y los hermanos Melina, Celina, Betty y Luis Alvarez (si es que son hermanos).

Comment: @Gustavson, podría ser?
 Hector Barquero y los hermanos Alvarez, Luis, Melina, Celina y Betty, por estar presentes ...

Comment: Prefiero mi versión. No me gusta la coma después de Álvarez. Pondría rayas: Héctor Barquero y los hermanos Álvarez -- Luis, Melina, Celina y Betty -- ...

Comment: ES común en Colombia usar la forma 1 "Melina, Celina, Betty y Luis Alvarez y Héctor Barquero", la cual implica que "Melina, Celina y Betty" tienen el apellido "Alvarez"; sin embargo como anota @Gustavson si el documento es de caracter legal u oficial deben usarse los nombres completos (primer nombre y segundo nombre si existe)y apellidos completos (primer apellido y segundo apellido [desconozco otros países pero en el caso de Colombia las personas son registradas con segundo apellido que viene a ser el primer apellido de la madre]).

Answer (score 3):

Al final el área de lingüística me lo pidió así:

> Hector Barquero y los Alvarez, Luis, Melina, Celina y Betty por estar presentes...

Sin coma luego de Betty.

Answer (score 2):

No hay una regla para poner los nombres y, al final, el apellido común. Se suele decir el nombre y el apellido para no causar dudas (debido a que el apellido se utiliza para diferenciar).